# How to plot Socrata polygon in folium

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, polygon, folium

I would like to plot some data that I pulled from a Socrata source which contains geographic polygons for some neighbourhoods.

I have the data stored in a dataframe and I have built the folium map but I have no idea where to go next.

my `demo_df.head()` looks like this:

````
    name    fem_25_34   fem_35_44   fem_35_44   fem_45_54   fem_55_64   the_geom
0   MANCHESTER INDUSTRIAL   0   0   0   0   0   {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[-114.058...
1   EAST FAIRVIEW INDUSTRIAL    3   0   0   1   0   {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[-114.030...
2   CANADA OLYMPIC PARK 0   0   0   0   0   {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[-114.211...
3   FOOTHILLS   12  15  15  0   0   {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[-113.992...
4   SHEPARD INDUSTRIAL  13  8   8   22  32  {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[-113.997...```
````

and my folium map is built:

```
map_calgary = folium.Map(location=[latitude, longitude], zoom_start=11)
map_calgary
```

How do I plot the `demo_df['the_geom']` column in folium?

Answer (score 0):

It appears `the_geom` values are represented as a valid GeoJSON objects meaning it could be visualized in folium via [GeoJSON layer](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html#GeoJSON/TopoJSON-Overlays) like this:

```
from folium import folium
from folium.features import GeoJson
from pandas import DataFrame


# constructing demo_df DataFrame from Socrata source goes here..

#init map
m = folium.Map(location=[45.137451890638886,-68.13734351262877], zoom_start=5)
#iterate over DataFrame rows and add GeoJson layer
for index, row in demo_df.iterrows():
    GeoJson(
        row['the_geom'],
        name='geojson'
    ).add_to(m)
```